# Several Facebook likes with just one action?

Tags: php, facebook, button, facebook-like

Is it possible to simoltaneoulsy like several pages with the same button? How would you do that in php?

What I want is that when users click the button they will we prompted to like several pages at the same time

Comment: That sounds a little spammy. Are the pages related? Do they have the same admin(s)?

Answer (score 3):

No the API doesn't support programmaticly liking a page and the like buttons as given by Facebook to embed in you website can only like a single page. If Facebook would allow this it would immidiatly be misused for all kinds of spam related activities.

[Details from Facebook OpenGraph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/)